# Need Help! <option> tag

Tags: php

Need Help! I want to stay the information of my option value when I update my data. How can I do that? Thank you

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>
    <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
        <option value="activate" <?php if(isset($status) and $status == 'activate') {echo "selected";}?>>Activate</option>
        <option value="draft" <?php if(isset($status) and $status == 'draft') {echo "selected";}?>>Draft</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Using mysqli php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Very simple, just creates an event "on change".  When it detects change, it will send a post request to save.php with relevant information like status of the current check box.  From there, you can write your own processing PHP that works with a database.

```
$("#status").on("change", function () {
    $.post("save.php", {
        status: $(this).val();
    }, function (data) {
        //yay, it's been saved.
    });
})
```

Comment: It will change the data in database table also? using this?

Comment: If you still need help, just let me know.

Comment: I will update you if this code is solve my problem. Thankyou so much Mr.